# spring mvc.все время выходит ошибка 404.помогите п.ж.л

Tags: mvc, spring

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылки не находят controller который должен обрабатывать запрос.что я тут делаю не так??

Comment: тут конечно другое.но другие свои примеры делаю примерно так.тут HelloController выдает hello.jsp a в hello.jsp есть форма которую обрабатывает контроллер req и выдает req.jsp

Comment: Пожалуйста, выложите Ваш код в виде текста, а не скриншотов. Так выше вероятность, что Вашим вопросом заинтересуются и Вы получите помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вы и так уже используете `ModelAndView`, то почему его не возвращаете в ответе сервиса?
2. Параметры login и password лучше получать через `@RequestParam`.
3. Запрос на аутентификацию правильнее отправлять через POST.
4. И почему бы не использовать Spring Security для этих задач?
5. Если вы указываете в `action` ссылку без лидирующего слэша, то это будет относительный путь, то есть `/hello.jsp/reg`, а не `/reg`, как в настройках контроллеров. Добавьте слэш - и все должно заработать.

Оффтоп относительно реализации... 
Что вы хотите показать таким примером? Если это кусок обучающего курса, который пойдет студентам каким-нибудь, то подумайте об ущербе? Вы даете человеку вариант реализации типовой задачи, который невозможен в реальности. Ни одно приложение не должно быть защищено вот таким способом. Есть стандарты, о которых можно и нужно рассказывать. Хотите продемонстрировать работу с `ServletRequest`, тогда просто передайте какой-нибудь текст или число, чтобы оно пробросилось через контроллер в модель нового view, но, уж, точно не закладывайте в фундамент знания неправильные подходы к реализации типовых алгоритмов.

Comment: Спасибо.Нет  было для себя..